# Is the thread created by ctypes also under GIL in python?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, ctypes, gil

All python thread(in CPython) are under GIL.

What if the thread is created by `ctypes`?

For example, python just calls the below function through `C Library` and the function create a thread in `C` area not python.

```
#include<thread>
int createUnitTestThread(int sasAddr){  
    sasEngine->thread = new std::thread(....);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it the same or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not like *threads* are under the GIL, operations in the Python interpreter are (including stuff like the fetch and execution of most opcodes, so that's why threads that execute Python code run mostly interlocked).

Your C++ thread will run free as long as it doesn't call back functions in the Python interpreter (either user callbacks or functions coming from Python.h).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question, even though the `C++ thread` is not under `GIL`, it is still running on the `python interpreter` having the same `PID`, right ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Bad Things™ will happen if you call Python from a thread not created by python, unless you explicitly register it somehow.

Comment: @asleea: being a thread, yes (well, under Linux is a bit more confused because everything is actually a task, so you could argue it has a different process id, but whatever).

Comment: @o11c: probably, although I'm not sure, I never called python.h stuff explicitly from a thread; anyhow, the bit of advice is mostly useful for callbacks (which are supported and routinely used with ctypes).

Comment: @o11c, a thread can get a `PyThreadState` and acquire the GIL by calling `PyGILState_Ensure`, which is what ctypes callbacks do before calling the target Python function.

Comment: @SangminKim Yes, they shared the same pid, roughly we should treat the dynamic library as the part of procedure, although they have some special points